# Changing scale of axes in Julia

Tags: julia

I am importing some numbers from two CSV files and plotting a heatmap according to the below code

```
height = readdlm("./height.csv", ';', Float64)
deformation = readdlm("./deformation.csv", ';', Float64)
heatmap(10^9 .* (height - deformation), 
   aspect_ratio=:equal,
   title="Height - Deformation")
```

The plotting libraries that I have used to do this are GR and Plotly with the Plots meta package. Currently, the x-axis and y-axis of the heatmap consists of 256 units of length. It is possible to change the scale of the x-axis and y-axis. For instance, could I make each tick on the x-axis have length 256/900 of the current unit length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `heatmap(x, y, z)` for this.

I suppose you have 256 entries in each dimension and a total of 65536 entries.

```
x = 1/256:1/256:1 # an iterable with length 256
y = 1/256:1/256:1 # an iterable with length 256

heatmap(x, y, 10^9 .* (height - deformation))
```

This way each rectangle will have 1/256 unit width and 1/256 unit height. You may assign `x` and `y` to any other iterable so long as each of them contains 256 entries. You can even set them as arrays of strings.

You can set actual ticks using an iterator with `xticks` or `yticks` keyword arguments in a similar manner.